# If else statement error confused

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

Hello guys I was confused using the if else statement I know it is the basic in conditioning also other languages. Don't know what to do here, I would like that it has an if condition(check) then also inside I want that it has an else if but my problem is I have to else statement which is wrong cause I know that else statement will be use at the end of a condition

Here's my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $idno = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['idno']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $position = $_POST['user_type'];
    $YearNow=Date('Y');
    $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $idno;

    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE idno = '$idno' AND password = '$password' " ;
    $result = mysql_query($sql1) or die();
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);

    //,student WHERE studentvotes.idno = student.idno
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM vote_logs,school_year where vote_logs.idno='$idno' AND vote_logs.syearid = school_year.syearid AND school_year.from_year like $YearNow ";
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql2) or die();
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result1)<=1)
    {
        $_SESSION['idno']=$row['idno'];
        $sql_c = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE idno = '$idno' AND password = '$password'";
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql_c) or die(mysql_error());
        $faunc = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
        $_SESSION['SESS_COURSE'] = $faunc['progid'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $idno;
        header('location: plsvote.php');    
    }
    else if ($row['status'] == 'lock')
    {
        header('location: last.php');
    }
    else 
    {
        header('location: notification.php');
        exit();
    }   
    else
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo "alert('Username or Password incorrect!, Please try again.');\n";
        echo "window.location = 'index.php';";
        echo "</script>";
        exit();
    }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: You can't have `else` without an `if`.

Comment: You should indent your code, it will help you to find logical blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have imbricated your blocks, try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $idno = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['idno']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $position = $_POST['user_type'];
    $YearNow=Date('Y');
    $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $idno;

    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE idno = '$idno' AND password = '$password' " ;
    $result = mysql_query($sql1) or die();
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);

    //,student WHERE studentvotes.idno = student.idno
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM vote_logs,school_year where vote_logs.idno='$idno' AND vote_logs.syearid = school_year.syearid AND school_year.from_year like $YearNow ";
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql2) or die();
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result1)<=1)
    {
        $_SESSION['idno']=$row['idno'];
        $sql_c = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE idno = '$idno' AND password = '$password'";
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql_c) or die(mysql_error());
        $faunc = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
        $_SESSION['SESS_COURSE'] = $faunc['progid'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $idno;
        header('location: plsvote.php');    
    }
    else if ($row['status'] == 'lock')
    {
        header('location: last.php');
    }
    else 
    {
        header('location: notification.php');
        exit();
    } 
}  
else
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
    echo "alert('Username or Password incorrect!, Please try again.');\n";
    echo "window.location = 'index.php';";
    echo "</script>";
    exit();
}
```

With an indentation, this kind of problem is easily visible.

Comment: it always pop up the message in the else statment

Comment: @miming In which `else`?

Comment: Is the variable `login` set?

Answer (score 0):

This can be ok:

```
if ( //validate the email 
     filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) &&
     preg_match('/@.+\./', $email)
     ) {
    $result = mysql_query (
        "INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())"
    );
    if ($result) { // check for successful store
        // get user details 
        $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
        // return user details
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false; //unsuccessful store
    }
} else {
    //not a valid email
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && preg_match('/@.+\./', $email)) {
    $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
    if ($result) { // check for successful store
        // get user details
        $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
        // return user details
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false; //unsuccessful store
    }
} else {
   //not a valid email
   return false;
}
```

Comment: You can not use two else statement. You should remove one of them.